# Show that constant function is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

An exercise is asked in the book to

> Show that the constant function is integrable and find its value of integration.

I tried in the following way to show the statement

Suppose   $f:\mathbb [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ such that $ f(x)=\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is any constant. Let  $P$ be any partition on $[a,b]$, ie $$P=\left\{a=t_0<t_1<t_2\cdots< t_n=b\right\}$$   then **Upper Darboux sum** and **Lower Darboux sum**  we evaluate   by $$\begin{aligned} U(f,P)=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\operatorname{Sup}\left\{f(x): x\in [t_{k-1},t_k]\right\}(t_k-t_{k-1})\\ 
L(f,P)=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\operatorname{inf}\left\{f(x): x\in [t_{k-1},t_k]\right\}(t_k-t_{k-1}) \end{aligned}$$ Now what about the supremum and infimum  of $f(x)$? If $\operatorname{sup}\left\{f(x): x\in[a,b]\right\}=\lambda$ but then $f(x)$ is constant so infimum of $f(x)$ is also $\lambda$ which immediately follows that $$L(f,P)=\lambda(b-a)=U(f,P)$$ Further $$L(f)\geq L(f,P) ,\; U(f)\leq U(f,P) \implies L(f)=U(f)=\lambda(b-a)$$ shows that $f(x)$ is integrable and its values is $$L(f)\leq \int_a^b f(x) \leq U(f)\implies \int_a^b f(x) dx =\lambda(b-a)$$
Now how to show that the supremum and infimum of the constant function is constant itself with/without using *completeness property*?

Any sorts of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The sets you are considering the supremum and infimum of are $\{\lambda\}$ in both cases and hence we can just use the definitions in both cases.

Comment: That's I did to make my work complete. However, Im much interest to do proof without definition.

Comment: You can prove this using the definition of the supremum and infimum as I said above. Since $\max/\min\{\lambda\}=\lambda$ the claim is immediate.

Comment: I see now,  i interpret it incorrectly :D. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$(\forall x\in[t_{k-1},t_k])\;\; f(x)=\lambda$$ then

$$(\forall x\in [t_{k-1},t_k])\;\; \lambda\le f(x)\le \lambda$$

$$\implies \lambda\le \sup_{[t_{k-1},t_k]}f\le \lambda$$

$$\implies \sup_{[t_{k-1},t_k]}f=\lambda$$

This gives
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=0<\epsilon$$